# Distributed write job crashes remote machine with MongoDB server

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, windows-server-2008-r2, pymongo, distributed-transactions

Looking for any advice I can get.

I have 16 virtual CPUs all writing to a single remote MongoDB server.  The machine that's being written to is a 64-bit machine with 32GB RAM, running Windows Server 2008 R2.  After a certain amount of time, all the CPUs stop cold (no gradual performance reduction), and any attempt to get a Remote Desktop Connection hangs.

I'm writing from Python via pymongo, and the insert statement is "[collection].insert([document], safe=True)"

I decided to more actively monitor my server as the distributed write job progressed, remoting in from time to time and checking the Task Manager.  What I see is a steady memory creep, from 0.0GB all the way up to 29.9GB, in a fairly linear fashion.  My leading theory is therefore that my writes are filling up the memory and eventually overwhelming the machine.

Am I missing something really basic?  I'm new to MongoDB, but I remember that when writing to a MySQL database, inserts are typically followed by commits, where it's the commit statement that actually makes sure the record is written.  Here I'm not doing any commits...?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Try it with journaling turned off and see if the problem remains.